# Is it possible to use an alternative app icon from device data?

Tags: swift

since iOS 10.3 it is possible to use alternative app-icons. I am wondering, if it is possible to use images which are downloaded from a server (of course in the correct sizes) as app-icons after build-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.
The names of the alternative icons must be the same as indicated into the `Info.plist`, and they must be part of the app:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806808-alternateiconname